# Closed too early

Tags: support, specific-question

Right after asking this question I "realized" that the problem was the exact same as another I'd faced before.

I marked as duplicate and then tried outputting into a `/tmp` file instead of the source I was using `cat` on.

After I made the change I found that I was still getting the original error.

Original:

```
cat my.json | jq -S > my.json
```

Now trying:

```
cat my.json | jq -S > /tmp/my.json
```

I still get the same error. Should I open a new question?

[Problem with `cat my.json | jq -S > my.json`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403563/problem-with-cat-my-json-jq-s-my-json)

Answer (score 4):

I reopened your question, you can just edit it to say that you tried the solution mentioned in the other question but it didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks I found the solution so I closed

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride please don't do that, if you can. If you've found the solution, post it as an answer and accept it. That way, the next person with the same problem will be able to find the answer.

Comment: @terdon ok undeleted and answered

Comment: @Philip great, thanks!

Comment: And yet it’s gone again now.

Comment: @Scott It got closed again, this time as a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367127/combine-pipe-and-redirect-on-curl-and-jq, which looks to be an accurate duplicate (Philip had posted the same answer on his question before it got closed and he deleted it)